# My nodejs app SSL certificate is not taken into account (IBM CLOUD)

Tags: ssl, routes, certificate, ibm-cloud

I have one nodejs web app on ibm cloud:  MYAPP.eu-de.mybluemix.net.
I want it to be reachable over https on https://MYSUB.MYDOMAIN.IO
I own MYDOMAIN.IO, and added this CNAME entry in my dns provider: MYSUB.MYDOMAIN.IO.  0 CNAME   MYAPP.eu-de.mybluemix.net.
I purchased a certificate for SUB.MYDOMAIN.IO added the domain in my organisation, and uploaded the certificate. Note it is not a wildcard. I read that long ago bluemix only accepted wildcards, but I could upload my single certificate without issue.
I also added the route to the app so I have 2 routes in the settings, both with the padlock green:
MYAPP.eu-de.mybluemix.net
MYSUB.MYDOMAIN.IO

After all this, when I navigate to https://SUB.MYDOMAIN.IO, I end up on the app page (redirection working), BUT I get the security warning because the certificate is still the one of bluemix, not mine.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it sorted after swimming in an ocean of outdated ibm doc, I found that to use custom domain, the DNS config should be a CNAME to a specific domain name.
in my case, not `MYAPP.eu-de.mybluemix.net` but `MYAPP.eu-de.cf.appdomain.cloud`

This URL was always there in the list of available domain, but it was hard to find its use.

[https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/apps?topic=creating-apps-ssl_csr#ssl_csr?cm_mmc=TonyErwin-*-Data-*-WW_WW-_-SSLCerts](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/apps?topic=creating-apps-ssl_csr#ssl_csr?cm_mmc=TonyErwin-_-Data-_-WW_WW-_-SSLCerts)